# Next.js Dark Theme - Cannot prevent the page from reverting back to light mode when the page reloads

Tags: reactjs, next.js, themes, tailwind-css

I am having an issue with the theme hook in my next.js app. Upon reloading the page, the dark theme has an initial flicker effect before reverting back to the light theme. The localStorgae indicates that on reload the dark theme is initiated before reverting to light.

What I have tried so far:

1. As seen in the `UseTheme.tsx` snippet, I unsuccessfully tried to add an event listener for the theme before completely loading the page.
2. in `_document.tsx`, I attempted to save the theme change from dark to light and visa versa with:

```
if (theme === 'dark') {
                document.documentElement.classList.add('dark');
                document.documentElement.classList.remove('light');
              } else {
                document.documentElement.classList.remove('dark');
                document.documentElement.classList.add('light');
              }
            }
```

This should've allowed the themes to be traced and changed with the same alterations to the last useEffect in the theme hook but this did not work.

**EDIT:**

I referred back to the tailwind documentation and made changes to the `_document.tsx`. Also, the UseTheme had a few errors such as `preferDarkQuery` as a prop type which was removed and the code revised. This should have worked but I still have the same issue and I'm unsure how to resolve it.

**UseTheme.tsx:**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const UseTheme = () => {
  
  const darkQuery = '(prefers-color-scheme: dark)';
  const [mode, setMode] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    const mediaQuery = window.matchMedia(darkQuery);
    const userPref = window.localStorage.getItem('theme');

    const handleChange = () => {
      if (userPref) {
        const newMode = userPref === 'dark' ? 'dark' : 'light';
        setMode(newMode);
        if (newMode === 'dark') {
          document.documentElement.classList.add('dark');
        } else {
          document.documentElement.classList.remove('dark');
        }
      } else {
        let newMode = mediaQuery.matches ? 'dark' : 'light';
        setMode(newMode);
        window.localStorage.setItem('theme', newMode)
        if (newMode === 'dark') {
          document.documentElement.classList.add('dark');
        } else {
          document.documentElement.classList.remove('dark');
        }
      }
    }
    handleChange();

    mediaQuery.addEventListener('change', handleChange);

    return () => 
      mediaQuery.removeEventListener('change', handleChange);
    
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (mode === 'dark') {
      window.localStorage.setItem('theme', 'dark');
      document.documentElement.classList.add('dark');
    } else {
      window.localStorage.setItem('theme', 'light');
      document.documentElement.classList.remove('dark');
    }
  }, [mode]);

  return {mode, setMode};
};

export default UseTheme;
```

**_document.tsx:**

```
import { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document';
import Script from 'next/script';

export default function Document() {

  return (
    <Html lang="en">
      <Head />
      <body>
        <Script id="use-theme" strategy="beforeInteractive">
          {`
          if (localStorage.theme === 'dark' || (!('theme' in localStorage) && window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches)) {
            document.documentElement.classList.add('dark')
          } else {
            document.documentElement.classList.remove('dark')
          }
          `}
        </Script>
        <Main />
        <NextScript />
      </body>
    </Html>
  );
}
```

Comment: Hey, did you manage to fix the issue or not ?

Comment: @ShueiYang Hey, sorry for the late reply but I was not able to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

To address the flickering issue in your Next.js app when reloading the page and ensure a smooth transition between dark and light themes, consider including the following attribute in the root layout's HTML tag:

`<html lang='en' data-theme='light'>`

Comment: This didn't resolve the issue. It isn't a major issue for me but it's still quite irritating seeing it like this